# zeppelin 0.10.0: new ui issue with table column display

Tags: apache-zeppelin

i'm trying zeppelin 0.10.0 new ui, in which the column looks like this

[image]

However, the table has more columns that does not get displayed; if I zoomed out I can see more columns

[image]

How can I fix this display issue?

Comment: the same question, have you resolve it?